# HTML/CSS Print Layout issue - adding extra page on chrome

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page and I am trying to fix the print layout issues on all of the browsers. Here is the code

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
        * {
            overflow: visible !important;
        }    
        body {
            height: auto;
            color: #000;
            background: #fff!important; 
        }  

        nav, aside {
            display: none;
        } 

        a-page {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            box-shadow: 0;   
            page-break-inside: avoid;
            widows: 3;
            orphans: 3;
        } 

        #header, #menu, #sidebar{ height:1px; display:none;}

        @page {
            size: A4 portrait;
        }


        ul.grid-container {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    }

    body {
        background: rgb(204,204,204); 
    }


    a-page {
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm; 
        background: white;
        display: block;
        margin: 1cm auto;  
    }


    ul.grid-container {
        border:0px dashed black; 
        width:100%; 
        vertical-align: middle; 
        text-align: center; 
        table-layout: fixed;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-top: 0
    }

    ul.grid-container .container {
        border: 1px dashed black;
        width: 49.7%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative
    }

    p.fcards {
        padding-left:10px; 
        padding-right:10px;  
        text-align:center;
    }

    p.fc_sm {
        padding-left:10px; 
        padding-right:10px; 
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    p.fc_md {
        padding-left:10px; 
        padding-right:10px;  
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    p.fc_lg {
        padding-left:10px; 
        padding-right:10px;  
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .size_4x2 .grid-container li{
      height:7.4cm;
    }
</style>
    <body class="size_4x2">

        <a-page>
                <ul class="grid-container">
                    <li>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                    <li>
                         <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                    <li>
                         <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                </ul>

        </a-page>

        <a-page>
                <ul class="grid-container">
                    <li>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                    <li>
                         <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                    <li>
                         <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                </ul>

        </a-page>
        <a-page>
                <ul class="grid-container">
                    <li>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                    <li>
                         <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                    <li>
                         <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>
                        <div class="container"><p class="fc_sm"><span>test</span></p></div>                  </li>
                </ul>

        </a-page>




        </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lajin/myf8nfpk/

When I see print layout

1. On Chrome it add an extra page before each page
2. On FF the page loads fine but margins on top is different on first pages
3. IE there is Huge bottom margin as it shrinks to fit the screen

Any suggestions on how to fix the print page issues?

Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your problems have been caused by inefficient usage of margins, padding and borders.  I solved this problem by first stripping away the irrelevant code by removing class definitions that were never called upon and removing lines that I knew or suspected were not influential, test running the new code after each removal to ensure no difference was made to the performance of the page.

My next step was to add the following CSS code to the beginning of the CSS component...

```
*
{
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}
```

By default borders are not included in the defined dimensions of an area and are instead added to the outside of the area.  By using `box-sizing : border-box;` at the highest level you force each area's borders to be included within it's area.

The default behaviour of margins and padding can also be a cause of much hidden grief.  By setting them to `0` at the highest level you can then afford to ignore them until such time as you know they are going to be needed for a specific `class` or `id` definition, at which point you would define them as per normal.

Next, I changed the line -

```
margin: 1cm auto;
```

to -

```
margin : auto;
```

As your file is currently coded this has the effect of making it appear as if large amounts of padding surround the A4 sheet which can look fine on-screen, but it is still included in the printed area which can cause poor layout when printing.  There are a few ways of getting around this problem.  I would suggest regarding `a-page` as the A4 area and adding within that `div` a second `div` such as `a-page-text-area` wherein would be placed the actual text.  For now I am using `margin : auto;` to keep the page centred horizontally and using buffer regions to separate the pages vertically.

Finally, with the class definitions `ul.grid-container .container` and `ul.grid-container` you are relying on one definition to overwrite the properties of another.  In more complex programs this can lead to errors occuring in some circumstances.  As a matter of good practice I recommend placing all shared property definitions within a common `class` or `class`es and all peculiar property definitions in an `id`.  Please note that when opening a `div` code such as `class = "container-grid container-all"` can be used to apply the attributes of more than one class to that `div`.

The complete code that I used to fix your problem follows...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        >

        <style type = "text/css">
            *
            {
                box-sizing : border-box;
                margin     : 0;
                padding    : 0;
            }

            @media print
            {
                @page
                {
                    size : A4 portrait;
                }

                .a-page
                {
                    float             : left;
                    page-break-inside : avoid;
                } 

                body
                {
                    background : #fff!important; 
                }  
            }

            body
            {
                background : rgb( 204, 204, 204 ); 
            }

            .a-page
            {
                background : white;
                display    : block;
                height     : 29.7cm; 
                margin     : auto;
                width      : 21cm;
            }

            .buffer-region
            {
                min-height : 20px;
            }

            .container
            {
                border : 1px dashed black;
                width  : 50%;
            }

            .fc_sm
            {
                font-size : 1em;
                left      : 50%;
                margin    : 0;
                position  : absolute;
                top       : 50%;
                transform : translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .grid-container
            {
                list-style-type : none;
                width           : 100%; 
            }

            .grid-container .container
            {
                float    : left;
                height   : 100%;
                position : relative;
            }

            .size_4x2 li
            {
                height : 7.4cm;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body class = "size_4x2">
        <div class = "a-page">
            <ul class = "grid-container">
                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class = "buffer-region">
        </div>

        <div class = "a-page">
            <ul class = "grid-container">
                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class = "buffer-region">
        </div>

        <div class = "a-page">
            <ul class = "grid-container">
                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "container">
                        <p class = "fc_sm"><span>test</span></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to ask / make them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to find a solution. It solves the problem with chrome but still there are problem with FF. Please see the screenshot here https://www.screencast.com/t/dFb1RM4ZBJ.

Comment: It works fine on my copy of Firefox.  I'm checking a couple of ideas at the moment, but for now what is your version of Firefox?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My FF version is up to date, I am using 52.0.1.

Comment: I'm still looking into this.  My Firefox Browser is much the same version, so it's probably not a versioning problem.  Do you normally use Letter or A4 where you are?

Comment: I normally use A4.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are in fact using that in Firefox?  Thus far the only success I have had in replicating the problem was when I managed to convince my browser that it was printing to a Letter sized page.

Comment: Yes, it was my bad I was using Letter size by default in FF. That solved the issue.